# ReactJS - Is it a good practise to open Modals asynchronously in a callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Quick backstory:

My application was growing bigger and I was adding more and more Modals for different user actions

Something like this:

```
export const App =() => {
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState();

    return (
        <>
            <Modal1 isOpen={ openModal === "modal1" } />
            <Modal2 isOpen={ openModal === "modal2" } />
            <Modal3 isOpen={ openModal === "modal3" } />
            <Modal4 isOpen={ openModal === "modal4" } />
            ...
        </>
    );
};
```

The state management was getting quite difficult. So I was thinking of a better solution and came up that maybe I could make ist work like `window.confirm()` works.

And I could but I am not sure if its a good solution... so I decided to post this question.

This is my approach:

```
const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    const newFileName = await openRenameDialog(fileName)

    if (newFileName !== fileName) {
      const confirmMessage = `Are you sure you want to rename the file ${fileName} to ${newFileName}?`;
  
      if (await openConfirm("Please confirm", confirmMessage)) {
         setFileName(newFileName)
         alert("File has been renamed")
      } else {
         alert("File was not renamed")
      }
    }
}
```

The benefit from this approach is that its not needed anymore to handle the Modal state in the `App` Component

Functions like `openConfirm()` and `openRenameDialog()` are created using a function named `createOpenModal` that works like this:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export const createOpenModal = (
    render: (onClose: (data?: any) => void) => JSX.Element
) => {
    return new Promise<any>(res => {
        const element = document.createElement("div");

        const handleClose = (data: any) => {
            document.body.removeChild(element);
            res(data);
        };

    document.body.appendChild(element);
    ReactDOM.render(render(handleClose), element);
  });
};
```

A example Project using some FluentUI Dialogs can be found here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-glade-b7eop

Is it a good Practise to do It like I did? Or is there a better way to manage many Modals?

**EDIT 1**

I Added a new example to my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-glade-b7eop

`App2.tsx` uses a more react approach of handling the State.

[image: App1 vs App2]

And like you can see `App2` is just a mess in comparison to `App1`. Because I needed multiple new handler functions to accomplish the same thing.

But if `App1` uses a React anti-pattern by manipulating the DOM directly, I was wondering how it would be Possible to improve on the approach in `App2`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a bit of an antipattern for react.  It doesn't make sense to be using statements like `document.createElement` or `document.removeChild` in react unless you have a really good reason.  I would go about this differently.  Have one `<Modal />` component, which is a wrapper for anything that shows up in a modal.  Then within that component, you can manage what shows up in the modal using a combination of the App's state, and subcomponents.  As a rough sketch:

```js
export const App =() => {
    const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState();

    return (
        <>
            {modalContent && <Modal content={modalContent} setModalContent={setModalContent} />}
            ...
        </>
    );
};
```

So yes your app is still managing the state of the modal.  I think that's fine.  Your `<Modal />` can then manage what shows up inside of it:

```js
export const Modal = ({ content, setModalContent }) => {

  const modals = {
    rename: <Rename setModalContent={setModalContent} />
    confirm: <Confirm setModalContent={setModalContent} />
  }

  return (

    <div className="modalWrapper">
      {modals[content]}
    </div>

  )

}
```

So in a general sense, your `App` gives a high-level picture of what the `Modal` should be doing (should it be open or not, what should it be rendering), and the `Modal` itself executes the instructions given by the `App`'s state.

**OR** If you want your `Modal` state managed within your `Modal` itself, you can put the state in the `Modal`:

```js
export const App =() => (
  <>
    <Modal />
    ...
  </>
);
```

```js
export const Modal = () => {
  const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState()

  const modals = {
    rename: <RenameDialog setModalContent={setModalContent} />
    confirm: <ConfirmDialog setModalContent={setModalContent }/>
  }

  return (
    {modalContent && modals[modalContent]}
  )

}
```

Then your buttons can affect the `setModalContent` callback. Its just a matter or how you want to keep things organized.  The second way is neater, but you may need a way to set the modal content from outside any of the modal subcomponents, in which case you'll need the `setModalContent` higher up the chain, as in the first scenario.  Or if the app is getting really big, inplement redux and get rid of the prop drilling.  Just some ideas to play with.

Comment: Why not replace those <> with React.Fragment tags? Explicit is better than implicit

Comment: I was just echoing his original code...I don't think using `<>` vs `<React.Fragment>` is really the topic of this discussion?

Comment: @duhaime i know it's off-topic but i also use it always, cause it's shorter. is it a bad practice?

Comment: It's a question of philosophy. I tend to endorse the statements in "The Zen of Python" (the poem you get if you `import this` in the Python interpreter). One tenant in there is that explicit is better than implicit, which I wholly endorse...

Comment: I know that ist not a good practice to manipulate the DOM directly in React. But is it really that wrong? Library’s like MaterialUI or FluentUI also render their Dialogs outside of the default #root element. 

I will add to my code sandbox a example of doing it the React way ASAP. I came up with my solution because I thought that the React way could be simplified.

Comment: I mean theres many ways to skin a cat.  What you came up with works.  If that works for you, great.  Is it best practice?  I personally don't think so.  I think in most react projects, you're more likely to see modals managed as a react component rather than managed through `document` methods.  It really comes down to style and organization.